# how can i merge these SwiftUI async tasks in one task to get a correct result from function when changing one of the parameter of that func

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, func

I want to update and use container members in picker , textfield and get price function.

```
struct PropertyContainer: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: PropertyContainer, rhs: PropertyContainer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.fromQty == rhs.fromQty && lhs.fromCurrency == rhs.fromCurrency && lhs.toCurrency == rhs.toCurrency && lhs.toQty == rhs.toQty
    }
    @State var toQty: Double = 1.0
    @State var toCurrency: String = "ETH"
    @State var fromQty: Double = 1.0
    @State var fromCurrency: String = "BTC"
}

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var propertyContainer = PropertyContainer()
```

using memebers of container in text field and picker
so I need updates for getprice func.

```
.task(id: propertyContainer) {
            do {
                price = try await listMaker.getPrice(fromCurrency: propertyContainer.fromCurrency, fromQty: propertyContainer.fromQty, toCurrency: propertyContainer.toCurrency, toQty: propertyContainer.toQty, type: "Fixed")
                print(propertyContainer.fromCurrency)
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all of your function calls are the same you could do it with a bit of refactoring:

1. Create a struct that contains all the properties you want to react to (Note: as you did not provide the properties e.g. `toQty`... this will be a general example):

   ```
   struct PropertyContainer: Equatable{ //important to conform to Equatable
       var property1: Bool = true
       var property2: Bool = true
       // and so on....
   }
   ```
2. Create a `@State` var that holds your properties in your View:

   ```
   @State private var propertyContainer = PropertyContainer()
   ```
3. Create your task as follows:

   ```
   .task(id: propertyContainer) {
    do {
    price =
        try await listMaker.getPrice(fromCurrency: fromCurrency, fromQty: fromQty, toCurrency: toCurrency, toQty: toQty, type: "Fixed")
      } catch {
      print("Error")
      }
   }
   ```

Now access (read and write) your properties only through the container `propertyContainer` e.g.:

```
Button {
    propertyContainer.property1.toggle()
} label: {
    Text("label")
}
```

---

When you change a property in your container the whole struct changes and your task gets executed.

### Edit:

Example for `Picker`:

```
Picker("", selection: $propertyContainer.selected) {//beware the $ for the binding
    ForEach(selectable) { selection in
        Text(selection)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not? Your question fails to reflect where this property has to live. So it´s impossible for anybody to give a definitve answer. Please update your question or ask a new one. If you try to access it from outside of your view remove the `private` modifier.

Comment: I want to define my property's as @State property in container and use each one as a picker selection, when I change picker selection that doesn't reflect to Getprice func.

Comment: I mean @State var toQty for example.

Comment: ok... I am new to stackoverflow, how Can I update my question?

Comment: ok check it out please.

Comment: @mamadaf Please add the complete code where you create your picker and so on...(e.g. your ContentView). I have tried my solution with a Picker and it works just fine. So the issue must be how you implemented this. This is going to take a long time and be frustrating for both of us if I have to ask you for every piece of code.

Comment: Also. The `@State` wrappers are not necessary.

Comment: thank you bro, I removed @State from members of container and its now working good! what's the problem?
thank you for help :)